# What do the square brackets at the end of this code line mean?

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and while coming across a reference site, I came across the following code snippet and I've been cracking my head to break it down ever since.

This is what I'm still trying to figure out:

```
int (*(*callbacks[5])(void))[3]
```

I've read through part of my C++ help books and (generally) understand the precedence flow. But seeing many operators bunched together has thrown me off and I'm rather confused. I've seen other examples and explanations [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348447/describe-int-var3void), but the extra [3] subscript on the right just complicates things for me.

I was wondering on how I should approach such kinds of complex code, ie. where do I start, what order should I follow, etc.

Would really appreciate the help! Thanks!!

Comment: fwiw I've been writing in C++ for a long time, and if I saw that I'd get up and go get another coffee before trying to figure that one out

Comment: You can try [this](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*%28*callbacks%5B5%5D%29%28void%29%29%5B3%5D)

Comment: @CoryKramer, or just use http://cdecl.org

Answer (score 10):

That is an array of 5 pointers to functions that take no parameters and return a pointer to an array of 3 ints.

I only figured that out because [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*%28*callbacks%5B5%5D%29%28void%29%29%5B3%5D) told me.  This is one of those places that a typedef would make things much easier to read:

```
typedef int (*PointerToArrayOfInts)[3];
typedef PointerToArrayOfInts (*FunctionReturningPointerToArray)(void);
FunctionReturningPointerToArray callbacks[5];
```

Comment: No usage of the term "dereference"? ;)

Answer (score 9):

Here are the beginnings of a primitive introspective "pretty printer" which lets the C++ compiler itself break things down for you:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct introspect;

template <>
struct introspect<int> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) { return os << "int"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct introspect<T*> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        os << "pointer to ";
        return introspect<T>::prettyPrint(os);
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct introspect<T[N]> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        os << "array of " << N << " (";
        introspect<T>::prettyPrint(os);
        return os << ")";
    }
};

template <typename Res>
struct introspect<Res(void)> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os ) {
        os << "function returning (";
        introspect<Res>::prettyPrint(os);
        return os << ")";
    }
};

int main() {
    int (*(*callbacks[5])(void))[3];
    introspect<decltype(callbacks)>::prettyPrint(std::cout) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
array of 5 (pointer to function returning (pointer to array of 3 (int)))
```

Comment: This is an awesome idea, why'd no one thought of this before?

Comment: It's also easy to extend it with "reference to", "const", "volatile"; and with a bit of extra work, it also shouldn't be too hard to extend to print argument types of general function types.  I just didn't happen to need those in this particular case.

Comment: Damn, that's nice.

Comment: I like that - almost like a `cdecl` that handles C++ types!

Answer (score 1):

```
int (*(*callbacks[5])(void))[3]
```

declaring callbacks as array 5 of pointer to function (void) returning pointer to array 3 of int