# C++ syntax understanding issue for 'using'

Tags: c++

I read technical documentation for some projects which are created with C++. I found a line of code that contains syntax I don't understand:

```
using c = char (& (cClass::* [1]) (cClass(*)[2]) &)[3];
```

I see the `using` keyword here. That means we deal with an alias, but what does this line do? How can I understand it? I think this creates a named alias `c` and assigns the result of the expression on the right to it. But what is in this expression?

Comment: Before digging into the details, let me tell you that the `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` parts are rather unusual. Are those really meant to be source code, or are they "annotations" used in the docs which are not meant to be C++ code? The type makes sense even _with_ those parts (I think?), but they seem to be quite suspicious, IMO.

Comment: This line of code was in a simple main function source code. Developers described it like "assignment to c using pointer to member function". As I can understand after reading C++ reference, there is pointer to 1 class method. Method accepts array of 2 elements with type as pointer to class, but what is purpose of using `&` operator on both sides of such expression and using [3] at the end?

Comment: @WideWood: it's not `operator&`. The `&` operator appears in expressions, but none of the occurrences of `&` above are in expressions. When applied to types, `&` means "reference".

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks I will remember

Comment: Is someone trying to be deliberately obtuse here? chi's answer explained how to decode this, but honestly even with experience it takes time to identify all the parts. If I were to see such code in a code review, I'd require that they break it down in components somewhat like chi did to make it more readable.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'd go further and say "no, there is no need to do that, find another way". I mean an array of size 1 of specific signature member function pointers?  Returning refereces to arrays of char of size 3?  Find another level of abstraction.

Comment: Someone needs to make a version of https://cdecl.org/ that works with C++.

Comment: The title of this question needs to change—the question has nothing to do with `using`, it even states that the one part of the expression that was understood *was* `using`; it’s *everything else* in the expression that is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here's how your type is read, step by step.
For the sake of clarity, below we declare a variable `x`.

```
T x[1]
```

`x` is an array (length 1) of type `T`

```
cClass::* x[1]
```

`x` is an array (length 1) of pointer-to-member inside `cClass`.

```
V (cClass::* x[1]) (U)
```

`x` is an array (length 1) of pointer-to-member-function inside `cClass`. Said member function takes `U` as argument and returns `V`.

```
V (cClass::* x[1]) (U) &
```

`x` is an array (length 1) of pointer-to-member-function inside `cClass`. Said member function takes `U` as argument and returns `V`, and can only be called on lvalues.

```
V & (cClass::* x[1]) (U) &
```

`x` is an array (length 1) of pointer-to-member-function inside `cClass`. Said member function takes `U` as argument and returns reference-to-`V`, and can only be called on lvalues.

```
V (& (cClass::* x[1]) (U) &)[3]
```

`x` is an array (length 1) of pointer-to-member-function inside `cClass`. Said member function takes `U` as argument and returns a reference to array (length 3) of `V`, and can only be called on lvalues.

Finally, to get your actual type

```
char (& (cClass::* x[1]) (cClass(*)[2]) &)[3]
```

we choose `V = char`, and `U = (cClass(*)[2])`, the latter being a pointer to array (length 2) of `cClass`.

More readable alternative:

```
using char3 = char [3];
using ptrTo2cClass = cClass(*)[2];
using ptrToMethod = char3 & (cClass::*) (ptrTo2cClass) &;
using c = ptrToMethod[1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got it!! I think that's why C++ is hard to learn for someone :) Especially to understand that `(& ... &)` means we deal with reference to array whose number of bytes is said in square brackets placed after it.

Comment: Yes, `using ptrTo2cClass = cClass(*)[2];` is more readable.

Comment: @WideWood The syntax of types is notoriously tricky to read, especially when nesting arrays and function pointers. It's simpler to define a few more type aliases and proceed making one step each time.

Comment: This is definitely a case of a programmer being "clever."  Its hard to read stuff like that!  If you want a full process for how to read such types, you have to use something ugly, like the [clockwise spiral method](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), which I have nicknamed the clockwise spiral of death.

Comment: I wonder how this would look using template notation, e.g. in terms of `pointer<T> = T*`, `reference<T> = T&`, `primitive_array<T, N> = T[N]`, etc.

Comment: @DanielSchepler That's indeed how I would probably write this. Given `template <typename T, int N> using arr = T[N];` and `template <typename Cls, typename Mem> using pmem = Mem Cls::*`, `c` is: `using c = pmem<cClass, arr<char, 3>&(arr<cClass, 2>*) &>[1]` which is much easier to understand (see https://godbolt.org/z/7hcnro for full demo).

Comment: Types are easy to read if you realize that the declaration mimics the _usage_.  Those are the same marks and annotations you would use on an instance of that type to be syntactically correct and yield the final innermost type on the left.

Comment: @JDługosz I'd say "easier" not "easy".

Answer (score 22):

Types have to be interpreted starting from the middle (where a variable name would be, if it was a variable declaration). You go the right, until you hit the end **or** `)`. Then you go to the left, until you hit the beginning **or** `(`. At this point you either interpreted the whole type (then you're done), or you're inside of `(...)`, in which case you discard them and repeat the same procedure (go to the right, then to the left).

Since this is not a variable declaration, you first need to find where the variable name would be if it was one. It's easier to do intuitively (once you get some experience), but a decent rule of thumb is to go from the left until you hit either `)`, or `(...)`, or `[...]`.

Knowing this, we can turn this into a variable declaration. I've added `x` as the variable name:

```
char (& (cClass::*x[1]) (cClass(*)[2]) &)[3];
```

Now we can start reading the type. First we go to the right:
                  `x`                          Variable `x` is...
                  `x[1]`                       an array with 1 element, containing...
(Nothing else to the right, go to the left.)
         `cClass::*x[1]`                       a pointer to member of class `cClass`, of type...
        `(cClass::*x[1])`                      (Nothing else to the left, skip parentheses.)
        `(cClass::*x[1]) (............) &`     a function with some parameters, `&`-qualified<sup>1</sup>, returning...
(Nothing else to the right, go to the left.)
      `& (cClass::*x[1]) (............) &`     a reference to...
     `(& (cClass::*x[1]) (............) &)`    (Nothing else to the left, skip parentheses.)
     `(& (cClass::*x[1]) (............) &)[3]` an array with 3 elements, containing...
`char (& (cClass::*x[1]) (............) &)[3]` `char`s

And we're finished. The type of the function parameter (`cClass(*)[2]`) has to be interpreted separately, using the same procedure. It's "a pointer to an array of size 2, containing `cClass`es".

---

<sup>1</sup> That `&` to the right of function parameters means it can only be called on lvalues (the function is "`&`-qualified").

Comment: Well that works great for Linux If I use GCC compiler.

Comment: @WideWood I was wrong, and it's actually walid. I just tested it incorrectly.

Comment: Wow, this is such a well-formed answer. I don't fully understand it, but it looks impressive ;)

Comment: @SodAlmighty Which part you don't understand? Want me to clarify something?

Comment: Well, this is the first I'm hearing about the lvalue `&` qualifier. It's a bit like the `const` suffix, right? As in, it goes after the function signature. Can this be used on normal member functions in the same way as `const` and `volatile`? Also, I've never really fully understood this practice of nesting qualifiers in type definitions. I assume it's the difference between "an array of three references" and "a reference to an array of three items"? The syntax is frankly mind-bending. Besides, I wasn't even aware you *could* have a reference to an array, because an array is a pointer.

Comment: For that matter, can you even *have* an array of references!? Seems contradictory.

Comment: @SodAlmighty *"a bit like the const suffix, right?"* Exactly. Both are called "qualifiers" when used in this manner. There's also `&&`. *"Can this be used on normal member functions"* Yes, this is how it's normally used. *"I assume it's the difference between "an array of three references" and "a reference to an array of three items""* See the end of the next comment. *"mind-bending"* :P *"because an array is a pointer"* Arrays are not pointers. This is a common misconception. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Arrays can be implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements, and this conversion happens during most (but not all) uses of arrays. The pointer you get from such conversion doesn't exist in memory beforehand, and is computed on the fly when the conversion happens (just like addresses of variables are computed when you request them, rather than being stored anywhere). "can you even have an array of references" No, but this is somewhat of an artifical limitation. You can have arrays of pointers though, which are different from pointers to arrays.

Comment: Well....I wouldn't say that the addresses of variables "don't exist in memory beforehand". Variables are imaginary concepts, and under the hood, all the program knows is the address in memory where its contents are located. So in a very literal sense, the address is most definitely "already known" ;)

Comment: “starting from the middle (where a variable name would be)”—to find that is a quest in itself. Why can’t you apply the same algorithm but in reverse, starting from the outside?

Comment: @SodAlmighty Addresses are known only in the sense that they can be computed. They don't need to be stored in the memory for every variable. ...Let's say you have an array: `char x[1000];` It occupies 1000 bytes in memory. If you stored the address of each character in it (8 bytes on 64-bit architecture) next to the corresponding `char`, it would take up 9 times more memory. This is ridiculous, so it's not done.

Comment: @RomanOdaisky It's the easy part (at least for me), that's why I don't even try to remember the precise rule for doing it. I guess you could start from outside, but then you'd get the most important information last (i.e. you won't even know if `x` is a pointer or an array until you finish reading the type). And also you'll have to mentally reverse the parts of the type to make sense of it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that is clearly not what I meant. You were talking about getting the pointer from an array, or from `&variable`, and of course these addresses *are* known. Obviously when casting polymorphic objects, indexing arrays, or accessing an object's members, these addresses would need to be computed.

Comment: @SodAlmighty My point still stands. Consider variables on the stack: the address of each variable is computed as a fixed offset relative to the stack pointer (or something like that), so only one address is stored for all local variables in a function.

Answer (score 7):

Note: this is an adaptation of my answer at [What do the square brackets at the end of this code line mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207809/what-do-the-square-brackets-at-the-end-of-this-code-line-mean/44208201#44208201) and thus I've marked this as Community wiki to avoid getting duplicate reputation points.  (Of course, feel free to upvote that answer if you like this one.)

The template based C++ code below lets the compiler itself break down the structure of this declaration for you.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct introspect;

template <>
struct introspect<char> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) { return os << "char"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct introspect<T*> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        return os << "pointer to " << introspect<T>::prettyPrint;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct introspect<T&> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        return os << "reference to " << introspect<T>::prettyPrint;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Res, typename Arg1>
struct introspect<Res (T::*)(Arg1) &> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        return os << "pointer to lvalue member function of " << introspect<T>::prettyPrint
                  << " taking (" << introspect<Arg1>::prettyPrint
                  << ") and returning (" << introspect<Res>::prettyPrint << ')';
    }
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct introspect<T[N]> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        return os << "array of " << N << " (" << introspect<T>::prettyPrint << ")";
    }
};

class cClass;
template <>
struct introspect<cClass> {
    static std::ostream& prettyPrint(std::ostream& os) {
        return os << "cClass";
    }
};

int main() {
    using c = char (& (cClass::* [1]) (cClass(*)[2]) &)[3];
    std::cout << introspect<c>::prettyPrint << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output (with some line breaks added by hand for readability):

```
array of 1 (pointer to lvalue member function of cClass taking
              (pointer to array of 2 (cClass))
              and returning
              (reference to array of 3 (char)))
```

Answer (score 6):

After narrowing it down I just saw there already are two answers. Yet I do write a new answer as it shows an alternative how you can narrow it down with STL type traits, going from the outer to the inner.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class cClass {};

template <typename T>
struct Extract : std::false_type {};

template <typename TRet, typename TArg>
struct Extract<TRet (cClass::*)(TArg) &> : std::true_type {
    using Ret = TRet;
    using Arg = TArg;
};

int main()
{
    using Type = char(&(cClass::* [1])(cClass(*)[2])&)[3];
    std::cout << "Type=" << typeid(Type).name() << '\n';
    static_assert(std::is_array_v<Type>);
    using Type1 = decltype(std::declval<Type>()[0]);
    std::cout << "array[" << std::extent_v<Type> << "] of " << typeid(Type1).name() << '\n';
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<Type1>);
    using Type2 = decltype(std::remove_reference_t<Type1>());
    std::cout << "ref to " << typeid(Type2).name() << '\n';
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Type2>);
    std::cout << "member function pointer, cClass, taking " << typeid(Extract<Type2>::Arg).name() << ", returning " << typeid(Extract<Type2>::Ret).name() << '\n';

    using FuncParam = cClass(*)[2];                 // Pointer to array of 2 cClass
    using FuncRet = char(&)[3];                     // Reference to array of 3 chars
    using Func = FuncRet(cClass::*)(FuncParam) &;   // Member function for lvalue of cClass, taking FuncParam, returning FuncRet
    using FuncArrayOne = Func[1];                   // Array with one Func (WTF?)
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<FuncArrayOne, Type>);

    return 0;
}
```

This writes

> Type=char (& __ptr64 (__cdecl cClass::*[1])(class cClass (* __ptr64)[2]) __ptr64& )[3]
> array[1] of char (& __ptr64 (__cdecl cClass::*)(class cClass (* __ptr64)[2]) __ptr64& )[3]
> ref to char (& __ptr64 (__cdecl cClass::*)(class cClass (* __ptr64)[2]) __ptr64& )[3]
> member function pointer, cClass, taking class cClass (* __ptr64)[2], returning char [3]

To understand which next function was necessary in each step I output for example:

```
using Type_x = Type1;
std::cout << std::is_array_v<Type_x> << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_class_v<Type_x> << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_function_v<Type_x> << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Type_x> << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_pointer_v<Type_x> << '\n';
std::cout << std::is_reference_v<Type_x> << '\n';
```

The ones and zeroes give me a hint what to do next.

A tricky part was on the member function pointer. First there is no `std` type trait to extract the class, the return type and the parameter type(s). And then this was where the `&` came in place that I failed to understand first. Gladly I knew that you can append `&` and `&&` to a member function, and the MSVC STL implements `_is_member_function_pointer` via `_Is_memfunptr` which gave me an additional hint how and where to add the `&`.

My code stops here as I now understand all parts. If you wanted to go deeper, you could just repeat the steps.

When going back from inner to outer I added a `using` declarations in each step, so the code gets much better understandable. Again there was one surprise: the outmost steps suggest that `FuncArrayOne` should be an array of references to `Func`, but that is not possible, so it is just an array of `Func`.

To be sure that the results are correct there is a final `static_assert` with `std::is_same_v`.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Which part especially? Maybe I can improve the answer!?

Comment: I think he means that there is big source code of main function to explain. But if he will read answers above, he can understand it.